# Login Page redirects to login page after authentication against active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to create a login page against active directory. After a successful login, it redirects to the login page.

Here is the code, I believe may be the culprit.

```
    if (true == AuthenticateUser(domainName, uname, txtPassword.Text, adPath, out strError))
    {
           Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
```

If I use incorrect credentials, it states invalid username or password.
Should I instead implement SetAuthCookie in the if{} block?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In my web.config file there were incorrect parameters there.
I removed them, added the correct ones and now it is correct.